# Linux / Unix — pipe the output to join

Tags: linux, unix, join, task

I am very new at Linux / Unix stuff, and time to time I am doing some sort of exercise. 
I was doing my exercises till I came up to one part.

> Plain sort quotes.t5 and pipe the output to join.
>       In join use field separator, read from stdin and from quotes.comms, output to quotes.t6

The problem is, I don't understand what this part is asking.

> A few days ago I have ran this command on the server:
>
> ```
> wget 'http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=BARC.L+0992.HK+RHT+AAPL+ADI+AEIS+AGNC+AMAT+AMGN+AMRN+ARCC+ARIA+ARNA+ATVI+BBRY+BIDU+BRCD+BRCM+BSFT+CENX+CERE+CMCSA+COCO+CSCO+CSIQ+CSOD+CTRP+CTSH+CYTX+DRYS+DTV+DXM+EA+EBAY+EGLE+ENDP+ESRX+EXPD+EXTR+FANG+FAST+FB+FCEL+FITB+FLEX+FOXA+FSLR+FTR+GALE+GERN+GILD+GMCR+GRPN+GTAT+HBAN+HDS+HIMX+HSOL+IMGN+INTC+JASO+JBLU+JDSU+KERX+LINE+LINTA+MDLZ+MNKD+MPEL+MSFT+MU+MXIM+MYL+NFLX+NIHD+NUAN+NVDA+ONNN+ORIG+OTEX+OXBT+PENN+PMCS+PSEC+QCOM+RBCN+REGN+RFMD+RSOL+SCTY+SINA+SIRI+SNDK+SPWR+SYMC+TSLA+TUES+TWGP+TXN+VOLC+WEN+YHOO+ZNGA&f=nab' -O quotes.csv
> ```
>
> But the produced file quotes.csv was not good enough to get insight into finances and stuff so I need some help from you!
>
> Checkpointing. When finished this lesson you must get this:
>
> ```
> $ sha256sum -c quotesshasums
> quotes.t1: OK
> quotes.t2: OK
> quotes.t3: OK
> quotes.t4: OK
> quotes.t5: OK
> quotes.t6: OK
> ```
>
> - `quotes.csv`
>     We have a source file with stock prices data
>     Lines are terminated with CRLF, which is not Unix style. Make it LF terminated.
>     Means remove CR (\r) byte from each line. To do this use sed (man sed) substitute
>     command, output to quotes.t1
>     More info at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline
> - Run checkpoint to test if quotes.t1 is OK.
> - Use head and tail commands to output all except first and last line of file
>     quotes.t1 to quotes.t2
> - Make fields separated with pipe (vertical bar |) instead of comma.
>
>   ```
>   sed -re 's/,([0-9.]+),([0-9.]+)/|\1|\2/g' quotes.t2 > quotes.t3
>   ```
> - Numeric sort by third field(key), don't forget the new separator, output to quotes.t4q
>     Output last five lines, cut it leaving first and third fields in result. `quotes.t5`
> - Plain sort quotes.t5 and pipe the output to join.
>     In join use field separator, read from stdin and from quotes.comms, output to quotes.t6

If needed, I can post all parts of this exercise, but I am thinking you may know what I need to do at this part.
Mainly what I need to know what that join means. I searched on Google about this, but still I don't get it.

Comment: [`join`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/join.html) is a convoluted command that requires sorted inputs.  It can read from standard input if you specify `-` as one of its two input file names.

Comment: Mm... In main post I will edit task, and post full exercise I have

Comment: Your original question was fine.  Have you created `quotes.t5` and checked that it is OK?  If so, then I think 'plain sort' simply means "run `sort` with no options".  You'll need to read the manual for `join`.  There's an option to specify the field separator, and you may not need to specify anything more than that and the file names.  It isn't clear from the updated question which parts are given and which parts are your answer.  You should certainly show what you've got so far.  I suggest 'unindenting' the question text, maybe using `>` at the start of the line to quote it.

Comment: yes, i have OK on all of them, except quotes.t6 ( because idk how to make it )
basicly what i need is to understand `Plain sort quotes.t5 and pipe the output to join.
In join use field separator, read from stdin and from quotes.comms, output to quotes.t6`
what is this asking me to do.
What so far I have is 
`quotes.comms    quotesshasums    quotes.t1 to quotes.t5 `
I don't know how better to explain this.

Comment: If this necessary to solve this question, I would e-mail all the file I have.

Comment: Superficially, it is asking for `sort quotes.t5 | join -t'|' - quotes.comm > quotes.t6` (or perhaps `sort quotes.t5 | join -t'|' quotes.comm - >quotes.t6`; I'm not sure how you tell which is required, except by interpreting 'read from stdin and `quotes.comms`' as meaning standard input first and `quotes.comms` second).

Comment: `sort quotes.t5 | join -t'|' - quotes.comm`   worked great,  I got OK

Thank you mate !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring an abbreviated version of the comments into an answer.*</sup>

The original version of the question was asking about:

> Plain sort quotes.t5 and pipe the output to join.
>   In join use field separator, read from stdin and from quotes.comms, output to quotes.t6

You need to know that [`join`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/join.html) is a command.  It can read from standard input if you specify `-` as one of its two input file names.

The steps are then, it seems to me, quite straight-forward:

```
sort quotes.t5 | join -t'|' - quotes.comm > quotes.t6
```

or perhaps:

```
sort quotes.t5 | join -t'|' quotes.comm - >quotes.t6
```

I'm not sure how you tell which is required, except by interpreting 'read from stdin and `quotes.comms`' as meaning standard input first and `quotes.comms` second.